# Split grid into cells according to white boundary

Tags: matlab, image-processing

If I have an image like this

[image]

I want to break the image according to the grid and save it in a matrix.
So if I knew the size of each cell then I can make a new 4-D matrix and save pixel values of each cell into the new matrix

like

```
[m n]=size(img);
a=ones(m/64,n/64,64,64);
x=0;y=0;
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n
        ti=i/64;
        tj=j/64;
        a(ti+1,tj+1,i-ti,j-tj)=img(i,j);
    end;
end
```

but I dont know how to do this if we dont know the size of each cell
we just need to split the cells according to white boundary

also I dont want the pixels of the grid, I just need all the pixels inside the gird lines

please tell me how to do this in matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an excellent Matlab demo that covers this problem, the [Microarray image case study.](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2573-dna-microarray-image-processing-case-study/content/R14_MicroarrayImage_CaseStudy/html/R14_MicroarrayImage_CaseStudy.html)

Answer (score 2):

this can be achieved using Hough Transform - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform

to detect lines and use them to calculate intersections.

This can be easily calculated using libraries like Openc which have ready made functions to calculate Hough transform,  here is a tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html

and a very similar purpose would be to detect lines in a sudoku puzzle for which a tutorial on how to use Hough transform is already mentioned in the following website: http://aishack.in/tutorials/sudoku-grabber-with-opencv-plot/